# JSP content in sightly

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, sling, sightly

A JSP file, like a HTML file can be requested directly in url. However, a JSP file gets compiled during runtime and HTML file doesn't (Although they are both requested the same way). Even a JSP file with no dynamic content gets compiled during runtime because they get converted into servlets internally. We can include a HTML file inside a JSP file but not the other way around. There are so many components involved in providing resource to the user (`Servlets`, `Request`, `Response`, `Webserver` etc).

1. Which component decides whether the file needs to be compiled by looking at its extension?
2. Sightly is a HTML file and can contain JSP code within its body which ideally shouldn't get compiled but does. How?

Comment: All JSP files are converted in to Serlvet. Once converted its not recompiled unless JSP file is modified. Even a simple HTML file saved as jsp will get converted in to servlet.

Comment: what about html file saved as html which contains jsp related code inside? This works in sightly!!

Comment: It will print jsp code as normal text.

Comment: No! In a regular HTML, jsp content is printed as normal text, but in sightly it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sightly can only be included as part of a component. Although sightly is HTML5 (ends with .html), sightly gets compiled by `Sightly engine`.
So it is possible to have a sightly file that includes JSP file.

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure I understand what your questions are, but here's my attempt

1. If there are no Servlets defined for a path then **Apache Sling** will figure out which "scripting engine" to use based on things like the http request method and the extension (.jsp vs .html). [See here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html). It's up to the engine (e.g. the JSP engine or the Sightly engine) to figure out what to do with the request after that.
2. If you have JSP code written inside a sightly file it will simply get printed out in the response. I've tested this using the [Sightly Repl](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sightly-repl) on my localhost.

so a sightly file `foo.html` with contents

```
<c:set var="foo" value="bar"/>
<div>${foo}</div>
```

Results in a response that looks like this.

```
<c:set var="foo" value="bar"/>
<div></div>
```

You can see that Sightly doesn't anything to strip out or evaluate the jsp tag. the `${foo}` would go away because there is no Sightly variable called foo in scope.

---

Another note: You can actually include a JSP file from Sightly.

Here's an example from [Adobe's docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/block-statements.html#include):

```
<section data-sly-include="path/to/template.jsp"></section>
```